# Searching Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA to search many workbooks with multiple sheets in each workbook
this line is were the text string required to find in any of the workbooks goes

strSearch = "Ian"

however it returns any bit of text with "ian" in it such as Italian or Diana
How might I change this to be Case specific please
Newbie here please be kind

Answer (score 0):

This should work (add in the missing variables, eg `wb`, `ws`)

```
Dim strSearch as String
Dim foundCel as Range
strSearch = "Ian"
Set foundCel = wb.ws.Cells.Find(What:=strSearch, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Debug.Print "Found in: " & foundCel.Address
```